# remove SQL duplicate values, distinct not working

Tags: sql, unique, distinct, nexusdb

```
SELECT BM.PUser, 
   BM.Desc, BM.Price, 
   BM.Info,
   CAST (CASE 
      WHEN BI.Closed = 'E' then BQ.Qty-BQ.Consign-(SUM(BD.QtySold))
      ELSE BQ.Qty-BQ.Consign
   END as int) as Stock
FROM BINVOICE BI
 , BDETAIL BD
 , BQTY BQ
 , BMASTER BM
WHERE (BD.User = BI.User)
   AND 
  (BQ.PartNo = BD.PartNo)
   AND
  (BQ.PartNo = BM.PartNo)
   AND
  (BM.Price > 0.01)
   AND
  (BM.Active = 'Y')
GROUP BY BM.PUser, BM.Price,
     BM.Desc, BM.Info, 
     BQ.Consign, BQ.Qty,
     BI.Closed
```

My issue is that I want only one of each PUser to display, but some of them appear multiple times.  I believe the CASE I have made is where they are coming from.  I am not quite sure how to get around this.  Using SELECT DISTINCT did not work for me.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  It is used on NexusDB.

Comment: Show code with "distinct" select that you have tried

Comment: I it's only PUser you want "distinct", then that's the only column you should specify in the GROUP BY! (All other columns in the select list should be arguments to aggregate functions.)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: i am using an old version of reportbuilder because that is what i have been supplied with.  it is basically requiring me to have everything in the group by and will not work if i take any of them out.  same thing goes for the way i have comma separated my tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use Distinct
`SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;`

```
SELECT Distinct  BM.PUser, 
   BM.Desc, BM.Price, 
   BM.Info,
   CAST (CASE 
      WHEN BI.Closed = 'E' then BQ.Qty-BQ.Consign-(SUM(BD.QtySold))
      ELSE BQ.Qty-BQ.Consign
   END as int) as Stock
FROM BINVOICE BI
 , BDETAIL BD
 , BQTY BQ
 , BMASTER BM
WHERE (BD.User = BI.User)
   AND 
  (BQ.PartNo = BD.PartNo)
   AND
  (BQ.PartNo = BM.PartNo)
   AND
  (BM.Price > 0.01)
   AND
  (BM.Active = 'Y')
GROUP BY BM.PUser, BM.Price,
     BM.Desc, BM.Info, 
     BQ.Consign, BQ.Qty,
     BI.Closed
```

Comment: @utility might have not been used properly